# I need to pass the variables to three seperate text areas. How can i do this?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I need to pass var result1, result2, result3, to three separate text areas.
my code is not allowing me to do that. can someone help? thank you.

```
var overtimeRate = 1.5;
var regularHours = prompt("How many regular hours?");  
var overtime = prompt("How many overtime hours?");
var pay = regularHours * hourRate;
var overtimePay = overtime * overtimeRatePerHour;

var hourRate = prompt("What is the hour rate of pay?");
var overtimeRatePerHour = hourRate * overtimeRate;


function calculator() {

  var result = pay;
  document.getElementById("textarea1").value = result;

  var result1 = overTimePay;
  document.getElementById("textarea2").value = result1;

  var result2 = overTimePay + pay;
  document.getElementById("textarea3").value = result2;
}
```

html:

```
<body>
<button onclick="calculator()">Calculate</button>
<button onclick="reset1()" id="reset">Reset</button>
<textarea id="textarea1" readonly=""></textarea>
<textarea id="textarea2" readonly=""></textarea>
<textarea id="textarea3" readonly=""></textarea>
</body>
```

Comment: you are not calling your calculator() function

Comment: @koningdavid it's called as the "click" handler from a button. OP are there errors in the console?

Comment: Your code attempts to use "overtimeRatePerHour" before that value is determined.

Comment: Im calling the function when the button is pressed. @koningdavid

Comment: What @Pointy said, as well as hourRate.

Comment: What do you mean its attempting to use "overtimeRatePerHour"? @Pointy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Your order of calling variables if wrong. Always check for errors in your console 
.The spelling of overtimeRate is also wrong

```
var overtimeRate = 1.5;
    var regularHours = prompt("How many regular hours?");  
    var overtime = prompt("How many overtime hours?");
    var hourRate = prompt("What is the hour rate of pay?");
    var pay = regularHours * hourRate;
    var overtimeRatePerHour = hourRate * overtimeRate;
    var overtimePay = overtime * overtimeRatePerHour;


    function calculator() {

      var result = pay;
      document.getElementById("textarea1").value = result;

      var result1 = overtimeRate;
      document.getElementById("textarea2").value = result1;

      var result2 = overtimeRate+ pay;
      document.getElementById("textarea3").value = result2;
    }
```

Comment: It is only showing the first var not the other two. do you know why this might be happening? @SNAG

Comment: spelling of overtimeRate and overTimeRate

Comment: ok i changed the spelling an still not getting the result in the other two text areas @SNAG

Comment: Okay i had it set as overtimePay not overtimeRate Thanks for your help. @SNAG